# Number of outstanding shares per query

Tags: python, algorithm, intervals

I came across this question and i was able to solve it but inefficiently. My solution is a naive o(m*n) where m is the number of queries and n is the number of orders.

> You are given a log (std:vector) of orders sent from our trading
> system over a day. Each order has the following properties:
>
> - order_token: unique integer identifying the order
> - shares: number of shares to buy or sell
> - price: price to buy or sell each share at
> - side: false = sell, true = buy
> - created at: timestamp when the order was created
> - cancelled_or_executed_at: timestamp when the order
>   was cancelled or executed (filled)

> An order is live in the interval
> [created_at, cancelled_or_executed_at). That is, created at is
> inclusive and cancelled_or_executed_at is exclusive. Timestamps are
> represented as integers, e.g. milliseconds since midnight. You may
> assume each order is cancelled or executed in full.

> In addition to
> orders, you are also given a vector of queries. Each query has one
> field: query_time, a timestamp. The answer to the query is the total
> number of shares outstanding among all orders which were live at the
> query time. Outstanding shares are aggregated regardless of time, e.g.
> open orders to Buy 10 and Sell 10 aggregate to 20 shares live.

I was wondering if anyone had a better way to optimize my solution below with any data structure or algorithm. i'm sure there is. It's a c++ question but I did my solution in python for my convenience

```
def calculate_outstanding_shares(orders, queries):
    result = {}

    for query in queries:
        live_trades = 0
        for order in orders:
            if query > order[4] and query < order[5]:
                live_trades += order[1]
                
        result[query] = live_trades

    return result


# Example usage
orders = [
    [3, 15, 200, True, 2000, 4000],
    [1,10,100,True,0,5000],
    [4, 25, 250, False, 2500, 6000],
    [2,20,150,False,1000,3000],
]

queries = [
    500,  # Before any order
    1500,  # Inside the duration of the first buy order
    2500,  # Inside the duration of both buy orders and the start of the second sell order
    3500,  # Inside the duration of the second sell order and after the first sell order ends
    5500  # After all orders have ended
]

result = calculate_outstanding_shares(orders, queries)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pre-process the `orders` list and on each time-point (starting/ending) calculate actual amount of outstanding shares.

Then for each query use `bisect` module to search for correct time position. That way you only do `m` * `log n` queries.

```py
from bisect import bisect


def calculate(orders, queries):
    outstanding_shares = []

    for a, b, c, d, e, f in orders:
        outstanding_shares.append((e, b))
        outstanding_shares.append((f, -b))

    outstanding_shares.sort()

    c = 0
    outstanding_shares = [(t, (c := c + amt)) for t, amt in outstanding_shares]

    return {
        q: outstanding_shares[bisect(outstanding_shares, (q,)) - 1][1] for q in queries
    }


# Example usage
orders = [
    [3, 15, 200, True, 2000, 4000],
    [1, 10, 100, True, 0, 5000],
    [4, 25, 250, False, 2500, 6000],
    [2, 20, 150, False, 1000, 3000],
]

queries = [
    500,  # Before any order
    1500,  # Inside the duration of the first buy order
    2500,  # Inside the duration of both buy orders and the start of the second sell order
    3500,  # Inside the duration of the second sell order and after the first sell order ends
    5500,  # After all orders have ended
]

print(calculate(orders, queries))
```

Prints:

```
{500: 10, 1500: 30, 2500: 45, 3500: 50, 5500: 25}
```

Comment: Good stuff. Never heard about the bisect module before to be honest

Answer (score 1):

I thought it might be useful to add an answer in Ruby that could be viewed as pseudo-code and easily adapted to any language.

```
orders = [
  [3, 15, 200,  'True', 2000, 4000],
  [1, 10, 100,  'True',    0, 5000],
  [4, 25, 250, 'False', 2500, 6000],
  [2, 20, 150, 'False', 1000, 3000],
]
```

**Step 1: Save the starting balance and create a hash whose keys are place dates or clear dates and whose values are associated numbers of shares**

```
def add_to_epochs(epochs, date, amount)
  if epochs.has_key?(date) == false
    epochs[date] = 0
  end
  epochs[date] = epochs[date] + amount
end
```

```
balance = 0
epochs = {}
orders.each do |_, shares, _, _, place_date, clear_date|
  if place_date == 0
    balance = shares
  else
    add_to_epochs(epochs, place_date, shares)
  end
  add_to_epochs(epochs, clear_date, -shares)
end
```

```
balance
  #=> 10
epochs
  #=> {2000=> 15, 4000=>-15, 5000=>-10, 2500=>25,
  #    6000=>-25, 1000=> 20, 3000=>-20}
```

**Step 2 Create an array of sorted dates and convert `epoch` values to numbers of live orders during the epoch**

```
sorted_dates = epochs.keys.sort
  #=> [1000, 2000, 2500, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000]
```

```
sorted_dates.map do |d|
  new_balance = balance + epochs[d]
  epochs[d] = balance
  balance = new_balance
end
```

```
epochs
  #=> {2000=>30, 4000=>50, 5000=>35, 2500=>45, 6000=>25, 1000=>10, 3000=>70}
```

**Step 3 For each query use a binary search to compute the ending date of the associated period and return the value of `epoch` for that date**

If, for example, the query were `3500`, the binary search would return the smallest value `d` of `sorted_dates` such that `d >= 3500`:

```
sorted_dates.bsearch { |d| d >= 3500 }
  #=> 4000
epochs[4000]
  #=> 50 live orders at time 3500
```

Most every language has a method or function to perform binary searches, and it is simple to code one in any event. The time efficiency of binary searches is (log n).

We may now compute the number of live orders for each element of `queries`:

```
queries.each do |q|
  alive = epochs[sorted_dates.bsearch { |d| d >= q }]
  puts "#{q}:  #{alive}"
end
```

which displays the following.

```
 500:  10
1500:  30
2500:  45
3500:  50
5500:  25
```